# Application asking for .Net framework 4.0 or higher when 4.6 is already installed

Tags: .net, windows

I have installed an application that requires .Net Framework 4.0 or above and .Net framework 4.6 is already installed yet when i try to launch that application it asks to install .Net framework 4.0 or above. FYI- Operating System Windows 7 32 bit
How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Does the dialog shown look like [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/content/binary/Windows-Live-Writer/78e92f3ba58b_9857/image_948f8f5e-a560-4aad-abf3-01a583422fa8.png) (but with different version number specified, obviously)?

Comment: Please edit the application's .config file and try [Redirecting Assembly Versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions).